# Adjusting font size of UILabel within UIView to different device sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have a view that has a few different blocks of text in it. I need the font sizes of the text to scale down when a user is on an iPhone SE, and scale up when the user is on an iPhone 7 plus, and not do anything on an iPhone 7. Right now the text is staying within the view left and right, but going off the bottom. See the pictures:

Everything looks good here:

[image]

The content is staying within the bounds left and right, but not shrinking to fit here:

[image]

Any ideas for what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Stack View seems to be the way to go. Happy to give credit to anyone who can explain how to do this with autolayout, or why you shouldn't use autolayout.